# Как реализовать управление программой с сервера админки?

Tags: php, c++, qt

Здравствуйте. Такая ситуация есть сайт. Есть программа на Qt на компьютере. 
Запускаем программу->Заходим в админку сайта->Нажимаем кнопку в админке->наша программа как то реагирует на это. Ну это приблизительно, но как это реализовать? 
Наверное надо писать сервер на Qt и в админке как то подкл. к ip компьютора или может уже можно как то подкл прогой к сайту, вроде Rest api, не знаю так получиться ли. Посоветуйте что нибудь пжл.

Answer (score 2):

смотря насколько быстро необходимо реагировать на изменения:

- отправлять запрос на php сервер с некой периодичностью  и получать список изменений - простой вариант.
- открыть на сервере PHP еще один слушатель на другом порте и отправлять всем соединениям изменения. 
  т.е при в начале программы надо создать коннекшен и держать его до закрытия.